# Accessdeniedhandler Could not Redirect page

Tags: exception, spring-security, access-denied

I have a small web application based on Spring MVC and Spring Security. I have difficulties setting my own AccessDeniedHandler that should redirect unauthorized users to my custom error page.
I use http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler) in my config class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. And also using AccessDeniedController. But when using sendRedrect it does not redirect my custom 403.html page.

Do you have an idea what I am missing here? What could be the issue? Thank you kindly for your help.

An excerpt from my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter super class:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**","/login*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "CREATOR", "VIEWER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();
    }
```

My custom AccessDeniedHandler implementation:

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAccessDeniedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null) {

            LOG.info("User '" + authentication.getName() + "' attempted to access the URL: " + request.getRequestURI());
     
        }
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/403");
    }
}
```

My AccessDeniedController

@Controller
public class AccessDeniedController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView accesssDenied(Principal user) {

 ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
 if (user != null) {
  model.addObject("msg", "Hi " + user.getName()
  + ", You can not access this page!");
 } else {
  model.addObject("msg",
  "You can not access this page!");
 }

 model.setViewName("403");
 return model;
}
```

}

The message shows in browser:

The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

Please Help me.........